# CSS - Align div to the right of text box

Tags: html, css

```
    <div id="header">
        <div id="search" style="float:right;width:250px;padding:20px 6px 6px 6px;">
            <form action="/" method="get" id="frmSiteSearch" name="frmSiteSearch">
                <input type="text" id="searchbox" name="keyword" size="20"/>
                <div style="width:22px;height: 19px; float:left;background-color:green;">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>          
    </div>
```

and a [jsbin here](http://jsbin.com/igodip/3).

I want to make the div with green background to appear right of the text box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Float the input left :

```
<input type="text" id="searchbox" name="keyword" size="20" style="float:left;"/>
```

[Example here](http://jsbin.com/igodip/9)

Comment: Thanks @ManseUK. It works. I will make this as accepted after 10minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Here is http://jsfiddle.net/Jams/Xns64/ link

```
    <div id="header">
        <div id="search" style="float:right;width:250px;padding:20px 6px 6px 6px;">
            <form action="/" method="get" id="frmSiteSearch" name="frmSiteSearch">
                <input type="text" id="searchbox" style="float:left;" name="keyword" size="20"/>
                <div style="width:22px;height: 19px; float:left;background-color:green;">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>          
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

see the code

```
<style>     
#searchbox, #button {
  float:left;
  width:150px;
  height:19px;
}

    #button {
  width:20px;
  background:green;
}   
  </style>


        <div id="header">
            <div id="search" style="float:right;width:250px;padding:20px 6px 6px 6px;">
                <form action="/" method="get" id="frmSiteSearch" name="frmSiteSearch">
                    <input type="text" id="searchbox" name="keyword" size="20"/>
                    <div id="button">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>          
        </div>
```

http://jsbin.com/igodip/11/edit

Answer (score 0):

Correct the code for green div with :

```
<div style="width:22px;height: 19px; float:right;background-color:green;">
```

Comment: Besides an answer, try to provide explanation on how the answer works (or point to the reason i.e. link)