# Cannot align text to the right

Tags: html, css

I wanted to ask why `text-align:right` is not working in this instance. So currently I have got a div and inside it is some map and text. Basically the picture below shows how it looks like right now and I want to align the text to the right but it does not work. Also I tried removing the float but it pushes my map down and still would not align the text to the right

[image]

```css
.locationdiv {
  width: 960px;
  height: 285px;
  background-color: #5c89c7;
  margin: 30px auto 0 auto;
}
#map2 {
  float: right;
}
.map2p {
  float: left;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 9px;
  padding-left: 145px;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="locationdiv">
  <p class="map2p">
    <span style="font-weight:800; font-size:28px; font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;">Hong Kah Diabetes Education <br>& Care Centre</span>
    <br>
    <br>Blk 528 Jurong West St 52
    <br>#01-353 Singapore 640528
    <br>
    <br>Tel : (65) 6564 9818, (65) 6564 9819
    <br>Fax: (65) 6564 9861
    <br>
    <br>Opening Hours:
    <br>Monday-Friday 8.30am - 5.00pm
    <br>Saturday 8.30am - 12.30pm
    <br>Sunday Closed</p>

  <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3988.7135200721114!2d103.71451791437465!3d1.3483820990165771!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x31da0fc328223963%3A0xe558feaadf0564e8!2sSouth+West+Diabetes+Education+and+Care+Centre!5e0!3m2!1sen!2ssg!4v1482145868140"
  width="390" height="285" frameborder="0" id="map2" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS - Align div to the right of text box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634977/css-align-div-to-the-right-of-text-box)

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure I see the problem. I added `text-align: right` to the bottom of `.map2p` and it's aligning right just fine. Check it out:

```css
.locationdiv {
  width: 960px;
  height: 285px;
  background-color: #5c89c7;
  margin: 30px auto 0 auto;
}
#map2 {
  float: right;
}
.map2p {
  float: left;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 9px;
  padding-left: 145px;
  right: 0;

  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="locationdiv">
  <p class="map2p">
    <span style="font-weight:800; font-size:28px; font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;">Hong Kah Diabetes Education <br>& Care Centre</span>
    <br>
    <br>Blk 528 Jurong West St 52
    <br>#01-353 Singapore 640528
    <br>
    <br>Tel : (65) 6564 9818, (65) 6564 9819
    <br>Fax: (65) 6564 9861
    <br>
    <br>Opening Hours:
    <br>Monday-Friday 8.30am - 5.00pm
    <br>Saturday 8.30am - 12.30pm
    <br>Sunday Closed</p>

  <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3988.7135200721114!2d103.71451791437465!3d1.3483820990165771!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x31da0fc328223963%3A0xe558feaadf0564e8!2sSouth+West+Diabetes+Education+and+Care+Centre!5e0!3m2!1sen!2ssg!4v1482145868140"
  width="390" height="285" frameborder="0" id="map2" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah I achieved the same by adding `text-align: right` to `.map2p` when inspecting the snippet.

Answer (score 1):

add `display:flex` to the `locationdiv` class in css,

also the padding left in the `map2p` needed adjustment

```css
.locationdiv {
  width: 960px;
  height: 285px;
  background-color: #5c89c7;
  margin: 30px auto 0 auto;
  display:flex;
}
#map2 {
  float: right;
}
.map2p {
  float: left;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 9px;
  padding-left: 100px;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="locationdiv">
  <p class="map2p">
    <span style="font-weight:800; font-size:28px; font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;">Hong Kah Diabetes Education <br>& Care Centre</span>
    <br>
    <br>Blk 528 Jurong West St 52
    <br>#01-353 Singapore 640528
    <br>
    <br>Tel : (65) 6564 9818, (65) 6564 9819
    <br>Fax: (65) 6564 9861
    <br>
    <br>Opening Hours:
    <br>Monday-Friday 8.30am - 5.00pm
    <br>Saturday 8.30am - 12.30pm
    <br>Sunday Closed</p>

  <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3988.7135200721114!2d103.71451791437465!3d1.3483820990165771!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x31da0fc328223963%3A0xe558feaadf0564e8!2sSouth+West+Diabetes+Education+and+Care+Centre!5e0!3m2!1sen!2ssg!4v1482145868140"
  width="390" height="285" frameborder="0" id="map2" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this instead text-align:right;

> direction:rtl;

use this instead text-align:left;

> direction:ltr;